# TypeError: cannot serialize - type tuple

Tags: python, xml, psycopg2

I am getting `TypeError: cannot serialize ('John',) (type tuple)` with this code in the first iteration. Why `SELECT name FROM potluck` outputs `'John',` and not `'John'` ?

```
('John',)
('Sandy',)
('Tom',)
('Tina',)
```

Anyway, i don't know if the problem is that.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import psycopg2
import sys

from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring

con = None

try:

    con = psycopg2.connect(database='events', user='demo')

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT name FROM potluck")

    rows = cur.fetchall()

    top = Element('top')
    for row in rows:
        #print row
        comment = Comment('Generated test')
        top.append(comment)

        child = SubElement(top, 'child')
        child.text = row
        print tostring(top)

except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
    print 'Error %s' % e
    sys.exit(1)


finally:

    if con:
        con.close()
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
child.text = row[0]
```

The text field of an element is usually a single string.

Reference: http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.text